# booting up in safe mode (hp zv600)

Tags: boot, safe-mode

What is the easiest way to boot up in safe mode? It seems like I have a lot of
trouble doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Just Googled the specification and out the box, it runs Windows XP. Providing you haven't installed another non Microsoft OS, follow these instructions:

To get to safe mode in XP, just press <kbd>F8</kbd> the moment that the picture/text of the BIOS has finished, but before the Windows flag logo comes up.

You should then be able to select safe mode as a option.

If you keep missing it, keep pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> every second from the moment you turn on the machine. You may hear warning beeping, however it should still work.

Comment: I just press and hold F8.

Comment: It's going to be F8 on any modern MS operating system.